# Running a Ruby program through PHP on iPage

Tags: php, ruby, server, system

Recently I have been doing a lot of development in Ruby and would like to implement some ruby code I have to my iPage web-server. It seems that the only way for me to do this is to upload my ruby files to the server and them run them from a PHP script by calling:

```
<?php

system("ruby web-test.rb");

?>
```

My question is should I even bother doing this, and if so how does the performance play into everything? For example let's say I wanted to use a Ruby program to parse text in a file for a specific string? Would I be better off just doing this all in PHP?

Comment: to parse text you can easily use php

Comment: Ya I know that was mainly just an example. The main reason is my school has been making me do Ruby development now, and I wanted to implement in the real world. But it just doesn't seem worth it...

Comment: Can't you use Ruby on Rails if you want to call the Ruby code from a web app?

Comment: What's not "real world" about Ruby?

Comment: How bout my world and cheap hosting plans?

Answer (score 0):

Generally you're better doing this completely in PHP unless you have a significant amount of code in Ruby that necessitates breaking it out into a separate program or where translating your Ruby code to PHP is too time-consuming to be practical.

Even then, don't forget you can have a mixed environment with a Rails or Sinatra app running in parallel with your PHP application. You can interface between them at the server level with mapping certain URLs to one or the other, or by making the PHP app interface with your Ruby app over an HTTP API.

You should evaluate if PHP or Ruby is the best call for your overall application and try and steer towards using one predominantly if not exclusively. They both have their various strengths and weaknesses, so it's hard to say which is best for you without knowing more about your requirements.

Comment: The poster has not talked about rails, quite the opposite, the example is just executing a ruby script.

Comment: @Meier I'm just suggesting Rails or Sinatra as a way of making a simple Ruby script into something you can access over HTTP instead of being dependent on a `system` call. That's a simple way to build out a [microservice based platform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microservices).

Comment: If it is a simple ruby script, rails and sinatra are overkill.

Comment: @Meier I don't know if it's simple. The [example on the home page of Sinatra](http://www.sinatrarb.com) works out of the box and it's four lines long, so I'd hardly call that overkill.

Comment: For starters, sinatra need to run as a separate process. Now you need to explain what a process is, and how to start it on a limited hoster.

Comment: @Meier It's not hard. Apache httpd and Nginx can easily accommodate both PHP and Ruby Rack applications, there's tons of references and recipes on doing this. Your presumptions about the hosting environment are  pure speculation.

Comment: Ok haven't gotten to Rails just yet... So let's ignore the fact that there is something that probably does what I'm thinking of, instead let's just do everything from scratch. I have built an HTML doc which send request to a PHP script using JQuery, which then executes the calls using PHP's system() method, and returns the output. So far it seems I can run Ruby scripts from this psuedo-command-line. I know this is a bad idea, but just how bad of an idea is it? (weak security)

Comment: @Asleepace Running a Ruby script that way could work, but if you need it to perform better, wrapping it up in a simple Sinatra handler is usually pretty easy, and that way the process stays running, ready to produce output. Start with the first thing that works, build up from there.

Comment: @tadman thanks for the advice, I will take a look at Sinatra!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a picture of the basic command line I made with PHP, HTML, CSS & jQuery which seems to be able to run Ruby files. Seems a little but much, but I'm having for so whatever!

[Basic Command Line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eBY2g.png)

Below is the basic terminal application which consists of two parts:

1) cmd.php - a simple php file to process system commands

2) index.php - a user interface to interact with it.

Its a pretty basic command line interface, but a good place to start!

```
<?php

// Be sure to set your password from 1234567 to something more secure!!!
define("MY_PASSWORD", "1234567");  //  <--- Important cange to your password

// Check if there is a command and password submitted before executing
if (isset($_POST['cmd']) == true &&  $_POST['key'] == MY_PASSWORD) { 

    system($_POST['cmd'],$output);  // execute request

      // Return error if output is not equal to 0
     if ($output == 127) { err("invalid command..."); } 
else if ($output == 1) { err("operation no permitted..."); } 
else if ($output == 2) { err("no such file / directory..."); } 
else if ($output == 3) { err("no such process..."); } 
else if ($output == 4) { err("interrupted system call!"); }
else if ($output == 5) { err("i/o error..."); }
else if ($output != 0) { err("error ($output)..."); }
} else {
    echo(-1); // Login Failed!
}
function err($msg) {
    echo("<span class='errs'>$msg</span>"); // error message
}

?>
```

And here is the user interface, be sure to save them both in same directory and update the password from 1234567 in the file above to something else...

```
<html>
<head>
<title>iCMD</title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js></script>
<style>
body, html { background-color:#000000; color:#1AD6FD; outline:0; padding:0; outline:0; margin:0; border:0; }
input { display:inline-block; background-color:transparent; font-family:monospace; font-size:14px; padding:10px; outline:none; border:none; min-height:60px; height:10%; width:100%; color:#FFF; }
#cmd-frame { background-color:#000000; position:fixed; bottom:0px; right:0px; left:0px; }
#frame { background-color:#111111; margin-top:-50px; }
#sys { overflow:auto; padding:10px; height:90%; }
.cmdo { color:#FFFFFF; margin-left:10px; margin-top:5px; margin-bottom:5px; }
.code { color:#FFFFFF; }
.cmdi { color:#1AD6FD; }
.cmdc { color:#39FF14; }
.errs { color:#FF2A68; }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="frame">
<pre><code>
    <div id="sys"></div>
<code><pre>
</div>
<div id="cmd-frame">
    <table width='100%' padding="0px"><tr>
        <td width='150px'><span style='padding-left:8px;'> [command-line: ~ $</span></td><td><input type="txt" id="cmd" name="cmd" placeholder=""></td>
    </tr></table>
</div>
<script>
inp("Welcome to the command line terminal! (V. 1.0)");
inp("Please enter your password to continue...");

mem = ["Hello, world"];
key = "";
idx = 0;

shiftlock = false;
$(document).on('keyup', function(e) { shiftlock = e.shiftKey });
$(document).on('keydown', function(e) {
    shiftlock = e.shiftKey
    scrolling = false; 
    if (e.which == 38) {
        scrolling = true;
        idx -= 1;
    } else if (e.which == 40) {
       scrolling = true;
       idx += 1;  
    }
    if (idx < 0) {
        idx = 0;
    }
    if (idx > mem.length) {
        idx = mem.length;
    }
    if (scrolling == true) {
        mem.push($('#cmd').val());
        $('#cmd').val(mem[idx]);
    }
});
$('#cmd').keypress(function(e) {
    if (e.which == 13 && shiftlock == false) {
        command = $("#cmd").val();
        mem.push(command);
        idx = mem.length;
        if (key) {
           inp(command);
           exe(command);
        } else {
           inp("******");
           usr(command);
        }
    } 
});
function usr(tmp) {
    $.post("cmd.php",{ 
        cmd: "echo success!",
        key: tmp
    },
    function(data, status) {
        if (parseInt(data) != -1) {
            key = tmp;
            out(data);
        } else {
            out("<span class='errs'>login failed...</span>");
        }
    }); 
}
function exe(cmd) {
    cmd = cmd.replace("read ", "ruby read.rb ");
    cmd = cmd.replace("save ", "ruby save.rb ");

    // Important to change cmd.php to where your php component is (same directory)!
    $.post("cmd.php",{ 
        cmd: cmd,
        key: key
    },
    function(data, status) {
        out(data)
    }); 
}
function inp(cmd) {
    $('#cmd').val("");
    $("#sys").append("<span class='cmdi'>[command-line: ~ $ <span class='code'>" + cmd + "</span></span>\n");
    dwn();
}
function out(msg) {
    if (msg) { $("#sys").append("<p class='cmdo'>"+msg+"</p>"); }
    dwn();
}
function err(msg) {
    $("#sys").append("<p class='errs'>"+msg+"</p>");
    dwn();
}
function dwn() {
    var e = document.getElementById("sys");
    e.scrollTop = e.scrollHeight + 30;
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Basically it can process only 1 request at a time, and keeps no track of memory in it self so is limited in what it can do. However, it works rather quickly and is quite powerful, so don't go typing in rm -rf ;)

Comment: Don't include the links of the sites which can be considered as spam.

Comment: Don't add images of code. It is much easier for people to try and reconstruct your solution copying and pasting code, rather than reading it from an image.

Comment: Ok I just posted a picture tho without any website info, is that ok? I'm pretty new here...

Comment: You can type the text and add an attribution saying _this content is taken from ... site_

Comment: @Asleepace Pasting in plain-text content is almost always better than linking to an off-site image. Those tend to degrade over time, so that image might not even exist in the future, rendering this answer useless for others with a similar problem.

Comment: @tadman ok ya that makes sense, the code I have to make that work is in 5 different files, how should I post?

Comment: Usually boil it down to the minimum, or a summary of what you did that solved your specific problem. It doesn't have to be your whole application.

Comment: Ok I boiled it down to two files, and tried to condense it a little so it might look a little funny but it works!

Answer (score -1):

It is possible to use ruby with cgi-interface. Some hosters allow this. I fear ipages does not allow this, they only mention php, perl and python:
http://www.ipage.com/knowledgebase/beta/article.bml?ArticleID=187
You can ask the help desk of the ipage if they allow you to run ruby scripts.

A basic ruby cgi script can look like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby

puts "HTTP/1.0 200 OK"
puts "Content-type: text/html\n\n"
puts "<html><body>This is a test</body></html>"
```

Try to put in in a file 'example.rb' or 'example.cgi' to try to call it with an url.

( Unfortunately many ruby users use a big framework called ruby on rails and have forgotten that there are also simplier options. You will not get much help from them. If you search on the web, look for ruby and "cgi".)

In my opinion, it is much nicer to parse text in ruby than in php.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, that definitely clears up some questions I had! As for running through CGI, I've heard that the overhead for parsing Ruby is not worth it compared to PHP. But however, I made my own Psuedo-SSH bash shell which executes Ruby code thru PHP (and is probabily the worst idea ever), but I'm having fun so whatever!

Comment: If you're going to do CGI, which is like using a fax machine in the modern era, you should **at least** use the CGI library. Doing it by hand is even more arcane and ridiculous.

Comment: Honestly, I have an odd fascination for old arcane technologies, especially doing things from the scratch, but ya that's what I thought lol

Comment: @tadman this is a minimal example, that works also on web hosters that are do not even provide shell access. It is basically a "hello world".

Comment: The [CGI module](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.3.0/libdoc/cgi/rdoc/CGI.html) comes with core Ruby if you absolutely must do this low-level like that. Speaking HTTP/1.0 in plain strings in 2016 is needlessly esoteric.

Comment: @tadman perhaps you missed the part of my question which pertained to my servers being hosted on iPage's esoteric technology. I have 3 options + CGI, which include: Python, PHP, & Perl (3P's?). That's cool and all, I like PHP more than Ruby ~ because of well my history, but I want more options, I want to go deeper. How do I run C?

Comment: How does C factor into this? Python's a good alternative if Ruby isn't available. Option 4 is to work towards understanding more about server administration and running your own small VPS. Those can cost as little as $5/mo. so they're quite affordable, and they give you the flexibility to run whatever you want, and whatever version. Using shared hosting is really a thing of the past and I'd avoid it if you can.

Comment: Ok awesome thanks for the advice, the only reason I'm using iPage is because I've had them forever so that makes sense. What's a better alternative, AWS? Also, about the C program: I want to make something with sockets so I could make a real-time multiplayer game (eventually) that I could play with my friends.